# large JSON file Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, large-files, swifty-json

I'm making a golf app written in Swift. Inside of my app I have a search bar where a user can search for a golf course. I have a large JSON file in Xcode containing a large golf course data base. I parse this JSON data base to give me the name and location of the golf courses and then display them as the user is searching in the search bar. The problem is the JSON file is 17MB and has roughly 18,000 golf courses, which is making the parsing process long and the golf course names don't start populating when the user starts typing into the search bar until about 6 seconds in.

I currently have a DataManager Class which goes and grabs my JSON file. I'm using SwiftyJSON to help parse the data and then append that data to an array so I can display it in my search bar's table view.

Any suggestions on how to speed up the process of parsing such a large file or reducing the file size??

Thanks in advance!

-Code for my data manager and my function that parses my JSON file:

DataManager:

```
 class DataManager {

   class func getGolfCoursesFromFileWithSuccess(success: ((data: NSData) -> Void)) {

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {

  let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("golfCourseData",ofType:"json")

  var readError:NSError?
  do {
    let data = try NSData(contentsOfFile:filePath!,
      options: NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached)
    success(data: data)
    } catch let error as NSError {
    readError = error
    print(readError)
     } catch {
      fatalError()
     }
   })
  }
 }
```

Function to Parse JSON (called in viewDidLoad):

```
 func loadCoursesFromJSONFile() {
    DataManager.getGolfCoursesFromFileWithSuccess { (data) -> Void in
        let json = JSON(data: data)

        if let courseArray = json.array {

            for course in courseArray {

                let golfCourseName: String? = course["biz_name"].string

                if golfCourseName != nil {
                    let golfCourse = GolfCourse(className: "PreviousCourse")
                    golfCourse.courseName = golfCourseName!
                    self.golfCourseCollection.append(golfCourse)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example of the JSON:

-I only need "biz_name", "e_city", "e_state"

```
{
     "id":18634,
"biz_name":"Twin Lakes Golf Course",
"e_address":"6100 Clifton Rd",
"e_city":"Clifton",
"e_state":"VA",
"e_postal":"20124",
"e_zip_full":"",
"e_country":"USA",
"loc_county":"Fairfax",
"loc_area_code":703,
"loc_FIPS":51059,
"loc_MSA":null,
"loc_PMSA":8840,
"loc_TZ":"EST",
"loc_DST":"Y",
"loc_LAT_centroid":"38.7803",
"loc_LAT_poly":38.819444,
"loc_LONG_centroid":-77.3913,
"loc_LONG_poly":-77.402822,
"biz_phone":"(703) 631-9372",
"metal_spikes":"U",
"play_five":"U",
"c_holes":"18",
"c_type":"Public",
"year_built":"",
"c_designer":"",
"c_season":"",
"guest_policy":"",
"dress_code":"",
"green_fees":"",
"weekend_rates":"$26 wknd",
"adv_tee":"7 days",
"FIELD33":""
```

},

Comment: Is the JSON data just name and location or is there other data in there too? Could you pare it down to a more simple structure with just the data you need immediately? Could you include a sample of the JSON?

Comment: There is other data in there but I only need three fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"containing a large golf course data base"* - you already mention the keyword here: ***database***

Dont use a Json file to do the job that a database is there for. Use a plain sqlite database or fmdb wrapper, realm.io or CoreData or something other than just a raw file. That way you can run much more performant queries, you will not have to hold all the 18k folg courses in memory, etc. The search for example will probably be faaaaar more performant using a CoreData database with search predicates than just you doing the manual search on non-indexed text data.

If you are still not convinced and still want to use json - make sure the json is not prettyfied, e.g. has no unnecessary whitespaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.

Comment: +1 Core Data is definitely the way to go (or any other database for that matter). Splitting the JSON files in smaller parts (based on the first letter a user searches for) is another non-db solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm still new to iOS programming and I haven't worked with CoreData, realm, etc yet. But I'll take this as an opportunity to learn one of them so I can use it in my app. Thanks I appreciate the help.